# XML DTD Schema, can I create an attribute with other's value?

Tags: xml, dtd

Lets say I have an xml element as follows:

```
<item name="ItemName" id="itemID" .... />
```

Now, lets say I have some attributes which I already handle / validate with my dtd `ATTLIST` schema.
I want it to do the following:
`if attribute 'id' not exists, set id=_name_attribute's_value`, or in simple demonstration:

```
<item name="itemName" .... />
```

will turn into :

```
<item name="itemName" id="itemName" .... />
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a default value in the `ATTLIST`. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE note [
    <!ELEMENT note (to,from,heading,body)>
    <!ATTLIST note id CDATA "myid">
    <!ELEMENT to (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT from (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT heading (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT body (#PCDATA)>
]>
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend</body>
</note>
```

If you display this file in e.g. IE, it will look like

[image]

As you see the `id` attribute incl. value is added. So technically this is possible, however keep in mind that an id attribute should be unique, this is what the DTD can not deliver.

Comment: Yes, you're right. my intention is not to have a default-value tough, but use another attribute's value. I guess that's not a possible direction to my need.

Comment: Ahhh sorry ... so I misunderstood your question ... this would be more a "transformation" than a definition problem ... hence I'd look into XSLT

Comment: you might find usefull input here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095190/xslt-v1-0-updating-attribute-in-node-set-based-on-previous-nodes-attribute